# Titanium "Uncaught Error: Requested module not found"

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

i have developed a native andriod mobile module in titanium appcelerator and now i want to add that module Alloy app..i have included the module in tiapp.xml and use the following line to access it

```
var sdk = require("ti.sdk");
```

where ti.sdk is modules ID....but still requested module not found error comes on execution.

Comment: have you clean build app?

Comment: No @MitulBhalia..i am just new to appceletor...how to clean build it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so you need to clean build your project first then if app is installed in your device/emulator then also remove that and to do that just select root folder of your project from project explorer and select "Project" menu from titanium studio and choose option clean.